# Body parsing does not work in nanoexpress

Tags: javascript, nanoexpress

I want to parse body parameters in `post` method, but email is empty:

```
app.post('/v1/authorizeUser', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
    const { email, password } = req.body;
```

This comes from the log:

```
body: [Object: null prototype] {}
```

This is my request:

[image: complete request]

If I understand the [documentation](https://nanoexpress.js.org/middlewares), I do not need to import `body-parser` via `npm i`. What do I miss?

Comment: Hello @dalisoft, can you take a look?

Comment: Which content-type is getting you from client?

Comment: x-www-form-url-encoded. I have updated the request screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting bugs. Issue can filled on GitHub [repository](https://github.com/nanoexpress/nanoexpress).

Try `nanoexpress@1.1.18`, your issue should be resolved

Comment: partial success, so I submitted new issue in GH

Comment: Thanks, we will continue discussion in GH issue